# Zero Secrets in Serviceaccounts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I was moving Kubernetes installation from old work infra to my homelab. In the process of movement, etcd snapshot was deployed on homelab, I've changed all certificates and etcd encryption key. Now apparently my cluster can't create secrets for serviceaccounts and so I can't use deployments either. What I've found so far is namespaces don't have secrets associated with serviceaccounts

```
    NAMESPACE           NAME                                 SECRETS   AGE
default             default                              0         29d
kube-node-lease     default                              1         719d
kube-public         default                              1         719d
kube-system         attachdetach-controller              1         719d
kube-system         certificate-controller               1         719d
kube-system         clusterrole-aggregation-controller   1         719d
kube-system         coredns                              1         717d
kube-system         cronjob-controller                   1         719d
kube-system         daemon-set-controller                1         719d
kube-system         default                              1         719d
kube-system         deployment-controller                1         719d
kube-system         disruption-controller                1         719d
kube-system         endpoint-controller                  1         719d
kube-system         endpointslice-controller             0         294d
kube-system         endpointslicemirroring-controller    0         294d
kube-system         expand-controller                    1         719d
kube-system         generic-garbage-collector            1         719d
kube-system         horizontal-pod-autoscaler            1         719d
kube-system         job-controller                       1         719d
kube-system         namespace-controller                 1         719d
kube-system         node-controller                      1         719d
kube-system         persistent-volume-binder             1         719d
kube-system         pod-garbage-collector                1         719d
kube-system         pv-protection-controller             1         719d
kube-system         pvc-protection-controller            1         719d
kube-system         replicaset-controller                1         719d
kube-system         replication-controller               1         719d
kube-system         resourcequota-controller             1         719d
kube-system         root-ca-cert-publisher               0         294d
kube-system         service-account-controller           1         719d
kube-system         service-controller                   1         719d
kube-system         statefulset-controller               1         719d
kube-system         ttl-controller                       1         719d
kube-dev            default                              1         690d
```

Timestamp 294days is about time when I've finished rollout of etcd snapshot in lab. All new resources created afterwards don't contain secrets. Even creation of deployment in namespace containing secret (eg "kube-dev" 690 days old) fails with reason of inability to create API token.
API server logs shows following

```
ar 14 08:52:54 controller32 kube-apiserver[1109873]: I0314 08:52:54.874017 1109873 healthz.go:244] informer-sync check failed: readyz
Mar 14 08:52:54 controller32 kube-apiserver[1109873]: [-]informer-sync failed: 1 informers not started yet: [*v1.Secret]
Mar 14 08:52:54 controller32 kube-apiserver[1109873]: E0314 08:52:54.959463 1109873 cacher.go:419] cacher (*core.Secret): unexpected ListAndWatch error: failed to list *core.Secret:  unable to transform key "/registry/secrets/default/lab": no matching prefix found;reinitializing...
Mar 14 08:52:54 controller32 kube-apiserver[1109873]: I0314 08:52:54.973314 1109873 shared_informer.go:266] stop requested
Mar 14 08:52:54 controller32 kube-apiserver[1109873]: I0314 08:52:54.973845 1109873 healthz.go:244] informer-sync check failed: readyz
Mar 14 08:52:54 controller32 kube-apiserver[1109873]: [-]informer-sync failed: 1 informers not started yet: [*v1.Secret]
```

If I would try to create new serviceaccount and associate it with serviceaccountkey, it will result in empty entry generated.
All help will be appreciated.